# How to submit a form in ASP.NET core using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a page with a top navbar in which I have a 'Save' button.

Below the navbar I have a form and I would like to submit it using the 'Save' button which is outside the form.

I can easily submit the form using javascript but it's not posted. Even if the form's method is 'POST' in the html, document.forms[0].method returns 'GET'.

If I change the form's method to 'POST' using javascript it will get posted, but the antiforgery token is not posted with the form and I get an exception. Probably the other fields are not posted either.

I looked up this issue but could not find anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can add `form` attribute to your 'Save' button. something like this `<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Save</button>`

Comment: Wow... that works indeed. Didn't see this at all, I'm more of desktop developer. 
Out of curiosity do you know why the other method doesn't work?

Comment: Also sake sure this may or may not work in IE ;(